# Cannot Resolve Symbol "OnClickListener"

Tags: java, android

I am getting the error *Cannot Resolve Symbol "OnClickListener"* and *"Cannot Resolve Symbol "V""*
I am starting to get into Java so I am not very good at this and not so familiar with the language

My code:

```
package com.emiliogaines.counter.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.More);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Antal);
            mTextView.setText("Some Text");
        }
    });

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar
        // if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Buy a book or a read a tutorial. Statements need to be in a method, they can't float around in the vast nothingness.

Comment: Ohh man!!!! where did you lost your `onCreate` ?

Comment: @malviň I think he ate it.

Comment: There are loads of examples on the internet that you could've looked up (Google: android button onclicklistener). Also, for future reference: you can instantiate XML-elements, like a Button, but you can not use findViewById outside methods in case you don't want any more NullPointers.

Comment: Yes, I have read a book but I didnt understand it.
And I mustve removed it by accident lol!
And no, nothing helped me when I googled because noone had the exakt same problem

Comment: Yes, I have read a book but I didnt understand it -> then read it again, if a plane pilot failed his exam, nobody is going to let him fly a plane :) Start with the basics of Java (Head First Java is a nice and easy start), then read about the basics of Android (Reto Meier's book is very good. I hear Udacity's course is also worth it). If you jump right in Android, expect a lot more of these issues, simply because of the number of new things to learn at the same time : OOP, Java, XML, Gradle, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you did that but please move the initializing and listeners to `onCreate()`:

Simply cut these lines of code:

```
 Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.More);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Antal);
                mTextView.setText("Some Text");
            }
        });
```

and paste them in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.More);
       final TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Antal);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  mTextView.setText("Some Text");
            }
        });
}
```

And then go read the basis of coding and it's standards.

Answer (score 2):

U must store this into onCreate method :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.More);

   mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Antal);
        mTextView.setText("Some Text");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still get ")" expected and ";" expected??

Comment: So you are missing this symbol  )  look at code before "expected "