# "cannot resolve symbol" 'show'

Tags: android, symbols

I'm a starting Android Studio user and have searched almost everywhere to find the answer to this problem but it seems i'm the only one with is problem. For some weird reason my android studio doesn't recognize the symbol 'show'.

[image: 1]

If anybody thinks he knows the answer please react. I'm really struggeling with this.

Thanks

Comment: You should really put in code and logcat when asking for a question like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Resolve Symbol "OnClickListener"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697222/cannot-resolve-symbol-onclicklistener)

Comment: You are writing your code directly into the class. It needs to be inside a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bring your writing code to a method. You should understand that :
- One package can contain many classes
- One class can contain many methods
- One method can contain many code statements

If you dont know about class, method, learn them first

Comment: It is the first time i´m actually doing something like this so yeah, everything is new. Can you recommend a place where it is easy to learn? Thnx!